# How to draw a web page into a memory DC?

Tags: c++, process, google-chrome, rendering, gdi

I would like to trick Chrome in to rendering its tabs in some memory device context of mine. Is this possible at all ? Thank you !

Comment: Not sure about Chrome but Chromium is open source so anything is possible with enough modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method in `chrome.tabs` called `captureVisibleTab`.  What you get back is either a PNG or JPEG.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html

That API is available to Chrome extensions - but you can't call it from ordinary JavaScript in an unextended browser.  I presume this is the technique used by ["Aviary Screen Capture"](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ncgcgghbabbopfcpgcjpfffdgnbadegf).

If you have a C++ program running in its own process, and you want to "poke into" Chrome - there are a lot of dodgy ways to do window hooks and capturing.  But why not save yourself the trouble?  Chrome is based on WebKit - just use WebKit directly.  Qt makes it super easy, for instance:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/examples-webkit.html

Comment: Sounds good. Some of the webpages will have Flash content, I guess Webkit will not be able to render the Flash content too ?

Comment: As is generally true with the plugin that starts with F and rhymes with "Crash"... your mileage may vary.  But support was added in Qt 4.5+.  http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27882-QtWebKit-and-flash-performance-issues

Comment: There are some hooky things for each webkit container.  Look in this directory and you can see how everything (qt, wxwidgets, chromium, etc.) has a little bit of code stuck in to WebKit to get it going: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/plugins